# Knowing blog name using blog id

Tags: themes, ajax

I would like to get the blog name using the given blog_id, how would I do this? I tried to search for the codex but cannot find the right information

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `get_blog_details` function.

```
$blog_details = get_blog_details( $blog_id );
```

Here is the [official documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blog_details).